# Toon shader in Ogre - glsl

Tags: c++, graphics, glsl, shader, ogre

I have tried many solutions found in the web ([ex. 1](http://www.bonzaisoftware.com/gldemos/non-photorealistic-rendering/) especially the correlate [paper](http://www.bonzaisoftware.com/downloads/NPRPaper_DE.pdf)), but none work for me.

Have you any advices on how implement a toon shader (or [NPR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-photorealistic_rendering) Non-photorealistic rendering) using ogre?

Realize shaders is my problem, then I'll apply materials to a compositor, that is not a problem.

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with the solutions you tried?

Comment: http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Enhanced+CelShading: no way. No error, no warning.. only black scene..